# App crashes when i uncomment a simple method

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements OnEditorActionListener, OnClickListener{

private EditText username;
private EditText password;
private Button login;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

    username.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
    password.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);

    userLogin();
}

public void userLogin() {
    String usernameString = username.getText().toString();
    String passwordString = password.getText().toString();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    return false;
}
}
```

The app crashes when "userLogin()" is uncommented. I dont get an error message or any indication why it crashes. The emulator just says "Login Screen has stopped."

I am new to Android development so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a problem of Java variable "shadowing". The important bits of your program are:

```
// these are instance variables
private EditText username;
private EditText password;
```

and in `onCreate()`

```
// these are local variables
EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

The issue is that the `username` and `password` variables you're using in `onCreate()` are **different** from the ones you've declared at the class level. So when you call `userLogin()` you will get a `NullPointerException` as the instance-level `username` variable was never initialized.

If you change your `onCreate()` to look like this:

```
username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

Then you will no longer have local variables and everything should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put,  you are declaring (creating) your view objects ( such as `EditText`, `Button`) twice: once as private members of the class, and once more in the `onCreate` method.

**To resolve this issue**, assign `username` and other view objects in `onCreate` without using the class name:

```
private EditText username; 
private EditText password; 
private Button login; 

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
  //... 
  username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username); 
  password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password); 
  login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
```

The problem arose because you were referencing locally created view objects to the XML layout, but your login method was accessing the global view objects which were never assigned to. I hope this helps!